# pretty printing from any format to a desired format

Tags: node.js, pretty-print

I am wondering if there is a way by which I can convert a format, let's say a tree to a format I want. Take the following example:

```html
a -> b, d
f - > c 
f-> v

I want to have this as an output:


a implies (b and d)
f implies (c or v)
```

Comment: Doubt any standard library has the output you want. 
I also doubt there will be any 3rd party library in `npm` would do this for you. Guess your best chance is to roll up your sleeve and code it out.

Comment: well, that is the last thing I want to do. But I bet you are right :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is practically the algorithm that you are looking for, but please take note that this algorithm doesn't support the deep conditions.

```js
function mathLogic(inputs) {

    var rows = inputs.split("\n");
    for (var i in rows)
        rows[i] = rows[i].replace(/\s/g, "");
    console.log("Rows: ", rows)
    var logics = {};
    for (var i in rows) {
        var row = rows[i];
        var rowSplit = row.split("->");
        var from = rowSplit[0];
        var to = rowSplit[1];
        var ands = to.split(",");
        if (!logics[from])
            logics[from] = [];
        logic = logics[from];
        logic.push(ands);
    }
    for (var i in logics) {
        var implyString = i + " implies ";
        var orLogic = logics[i];
        var ors = [];
        for (var j in orLogic) {
            var or = orLogic[j]
            if (or.length > 1)
                ors.push("(" + or.join(" and ") + ")");
            else
                ors.push(or.join(" and "));
        }
        if (ors.length > 1)
            implyString += "(" + ors.join(" or ") + ")";
        else
            implyString += ors.join(" or ");
        console.log(implyString);
    }
}

mathLogic(`a -> b, d
  f - > c 
  f-> v`);
```

Comment: Hello @Hans. Thanks for the code. Yes, I believe this is what I need with some modifications.